# Gitlab CI/CD Pipeline keeps failing for terraform plan/apply (terraform layered architecture)

Tags: gitlab-ci, cicd

So I currently I have a layered architecture with terraform. Here is what my directory looks like.

```
.
├── README.md
├── application-layer
│   ├── datasources.tf
│   ├── ec2.tf
│   ├── providers.tf
│   ├── terraform.tfvars
│   └── variables.tf
└── network-layer
    ├── gateways.tf
    ├── outputs.tf
    ├── providers.tf
    ├── routes.tf
    ├── securitygroups.tf
    ├── subnet.tf
    ├── terraform.tfvars
    ├── variables.tf
    └── vpc.tf
```

I'm having trouble with getting the GitLab CI pipeline to succeed at the plan/apply stages, specifically for the application-layer. The application layer pulls the state from the network layer so the ec2 instances in the application-layer, can reference security groups in the network-layer. The network-layer needs to be applied first, then the application-layer can be applied. Otherwise even running the terraform commands manually will fail. However, I'm having a hard understanding of how to translate that into the GitLab CI yaml. This is what I currently have, but the pipeline passes at plan-network, but fails at plan-app.

```
stages:
  - format
  - validate
  - plan
  - apply
image:
  name: hashicorp/terraform:light
  entrypoint:
    - '/usr/bin/env'
    - 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
before_script:
  - terraform init
  - terraform --version
  - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
  - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}

fmt-network:
  stage: format
  before_script:
    - cd network-layer
    - terraform init
  script:
    - terraform fmt
  allow_failure: false

validate-network:
  stage: validate
  before_script:
    - cd network-layer
    - terraform init
  script:
    - terraform validate
  
plan-network:
  stage: plan
  before_script:
    - cd network-layer
    - terraform init
  script:
    - terraform plan
  dependencies:
    - validate-network

apply-network:
  stage: apply
  before_script:
    - cd network-layer
    - terraform init
  script:
    - terraform apply --auto-approve
  dependencies:
    - plan-network
  artifacts:
    when: always

fmt-app:
  stage: format
  before_script:
    - cd application-layer
    - terraform init
  script:
    - terraform fmt
  allow_failure: false

validate-app:
  stage: validate
  before_script:
    - cd application-layer
    - terraform init
  script:
    - terraform validate
  
plan-app:
  stage: plan
  before_script:
    - cd application-layer
    - terraform init
  script:
    - terraform plan
  dependencies:
    - validate-app

apply-app:
  stage: apply
  before_script:
    - cd application-layer
    - terraform init
  script:
    - terraform apply --auto-approve
  dependencies:
    - plan-app
```

I have tried adding an artifact and a path to go into the folders instead of cd into each but that didn't work.
I have also tried adding a "needs" section to the plan-app that reads :

```
plan-app:
  stage: plan
  before_script:
    - cd application-layer
    - terraform init
  needs: ["apply-network"]
  script:
    - terraform plan
```

however I get this error "plan-app job: need apply-network is not defined in current or prior stages"

Answer (score 0):

The stages run in the order you define them. Here you have defined them as:

stages:

- format
- validate
- plan
- apply

The pipeline will first complete all jobs of stage "format", then it will complete all jobs of stage "validate" and then so on. It does not matter in which order you define the jobs. The jobs will run in order of stage.

Your job "plan-app" is defined for stage "plan", which is the 3rd number in stages. But in this job you are referring a job "apply-network" which will run in stage "apply" (4th number in stages).
Your pipeline is still trying to complete the "plan" stage, so it is unable to find the job of "apply" stage, as "apply" stage will run after completion of "plan" stage. Hence the error "apply-network is not defined in **current** or **prior** stages"

Either create separate stages for both application and network or I would suggest you to create separate pipelines for both.